# POST data method automatically

Tags: php, forms, post, postdata

I want to do the following is that i am trying to post data automatically to another url

```
$postid = $_POST['new'];
$tt = file_get_contents("new1.php");
```

Comment: i cant see any question here.

Comment: I want to automatically post the new ID data to new1.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of **`cURL`** to do this

```
if(isset($_POST['new']))
{
$postid = $_POST['new'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'new1.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=$postid");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
}
```